# Handling a "ledger" in MySQL and keeping track of the total balance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sort of simple ledger in my app. I keep track of each balance adjustment i.e. deposit $10 into an account with $5 creates a new row containing the amount of $10 and the total of $15. The $15 number is the part I'm having a hard time figuring out how I should handle it.

I can do it totally app code side with my DB adapter by getting the last row's total and adding to the new amount and creating a new total_balance based on that. This, however, feels wrong to me for some reason. I feel like I should be able to do this logic all in MySQL somehow.

Something like "create a new record WHERE user_id='123' and the amount is +10" and it'd make a new record with 15 for the total_balance *automatically*.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could investigate use of triggers.

Comment: I may be wrong on this, but what about just using the SUM() function in mysql?  `SELECT SUM(amount) WHERE user_id=123;`

Comment: @TimWithers ah, great point. I think I may be overcomplicating it. My only worry was speed. Each request needing to go through all adjustments, but maybe MySQL is fast enough this wouldnt be an issue for 95% of users. Ill try it

Comment: Generally, a ledger has a transaction table and an account table.  The balance would be in the account table.  By separating transactions and balances, the balances could be recreated from the transactions.